# How do I separate an integer with a dot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, decimal

I have a number, and the number of decimal places.

```
i = 1138602
d = 2
```

The result I want to receive should be this:

```
11386.02
```

The most stupid way that comes to my mind:

```
i = 1138602
d = 2
b = str(i)
i = Decimal(b.replace(b[-d], '.{}'.format(b[-d])))

Decimal('11386.02')
```

Which way will be more correct?

Answer (score 6):

Don't think about it as "separate an integer with a dot". Think about the actual *mathematical relationship* between 1138602 and 11386.02, which is that 11386.02 is 1138602 divided by 100.

```
output = i / 10**d
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to preserve the exact digits, so you should also show how to do this using the decimal module.